# Inverter a ordem do fwrite

Tags: php, formulário

Gente, alguém me da essa ajuda por favor ! Tenho um formulário onde as pessoas vão por links do youtube contendo músicas e irá gerar para mim uma lista dessas músicas no arquivo musicas.html.

Como posso inverter a listagem dessas músicas ? O arquivo .html insere cada link do YouTube abaixo do outro, sendo que a minha necessidade é que ele vá listando uma por cima da outra, assim facilita em não ter que ficar rolando a lista para baixo afim de atingir os últimos links enviados.

```
    <form action="" method="POST">
        <input name="link" type="text" placeholder="Link do Youtube" />
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Enviar">
    </form>

    <?php
        if (!empty($_POST["link"])) {

            $mus = $_POST['link'];

            $arquivo = "musicas.html";
            date_default_timezone_set('America/Bahia');
            $data = date('d/m/Y H:i:s', time());

            $fp = fopen($arquivo, "a+");   
            fwrite($fp,"Data: $data | Link: <a href=$mus>Click Aqui</a><br><br>");   
            fclose($fp);

            echo "Música enviada com sucesso !";

        }
    ?>
```

**Dúvida extra**:

Como faço para explodir esse link do Youtube para modificar o link do vídeo e levar até o link de um site para download do .mp3 do vídeo ?

> Exemplo -> www.youtube.com/v=AbCdEFgh_
>
> Explode com as modificações -> www.yout.com/v=AbCdEFgh_

O site yout.com permite fazer o download de .mp3 e .mp4 dos vídeos, assim quando eu acessar o meu arquivo musicas.html, terei este resultado:

> **Data**: 12/04/2016 17:51:21 | **Link**: Click Aqui | **Download**: Click Aqui

Obrigado

Comment: Você quer pegar somente o valor do atributo href do link ?

Comment: Isso, para modificar o link todo disso:

www.youtube.com/v=eXEmPLo_


Para isso:
www.yout.com/v=eXEmPLo_

Comment: Ok, vou postar a solução.

Answer (score 1):

Você quer inserir os dados no começo do arquivo, pode usar essa função.

```
function prepend($string, $filename) {
  $context = stream_context_create();
  $fp = fopen($filename, 'r', 1, $context);
  $tmpname = md5($string);
  file_put_contents($tmpname, $string);
  file_put_contents($tmpname, $fp, FILE_APPEND);
  fclose($fp);
  unlink($filename);
  rename($tmpname, $filename);
}
```

DUVIDA EXTRA

Você também precisa pegar o valor do atributo href da tag `<a>`, para isso, você pode usar a função preg_match()

```
$link  =   "<a href='www.youtube.com/v=eXEmPLo_'>video</a>";

preg_match('/(?<!_)href=([\'"])?(.*?)\\1/',$link, $matches);

print_r( $matches );
```

Resultando em:

> Array ( [0] => href='www.youtube.com/v=eXEmPLo_' [1] => ' [2] =>
>   www.youtube.com/v=eXEmPLo_ )

Espero que te ajude.

Comment: Basta inserir essa função acima do código que postei ?

Comment: Essa função grava um texto num arquivo, mas ela insere o registro mais novo na primeira linha, como se fosse uma listagem ordenando de forma decrescente. Então, quando for gravar o arquivo com os links que vem do formulário, você usa ela.